# How to convert a MySQL datetime(6) to microseconds

Tags: mysql

How do you convert a MySQL datetime(6) to a numerical expression of the number of microseconds since the unix epoch?

To clarify, I do not want only the microsecond portion of the datetime. I want the total number of microseconds for the year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 1000*1000*unix_timestamp('2018-04-05 10:13:25');
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. You've both been so extremely helpful. Thank you so much. I have to accept this one, because, even before the correction, this totally solved my problem. Thank you, Ajay. Thank you, Kang.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, but this returns the value you're looking for in seconds, so you will have to multiply by 1000000.

So you could use

`SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)*1000000);`

Comment: If I understand correctly, though, while this would be an expression in microseconds, it would lose the precision of the datetime(6). I need it not just to be in microseconds, but to have the correct number of them. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Oooh, I see. It returns it in seconds, but preserves the microseconds as decimal. That would work, then, yeah?

Comment: Correct, it will return as decimal as long as the argument you pass gives fractional seconds